# Can't delete Node with Cypher

Tags: spring, graph, neo4j, cypher

i am working on Spring Data Neo4j and use Cypher-Language for some Queries. Works fine so long, but delete a Node don't work.

For Example:

```
@Query("start u=node(5) delete u")
void deleteNode();
```

i use the dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-cypher</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

i cannot use version 1.7.2 of Cypher because it conflict with spring data neo4j and the kernel 1.6.

Can anybody help me?

i don't want to delete a Node with

```
repository.delete(5);
```

Because i also want to delete Relationships and any more.

Thx!

Comment: cypher before 1.8 doesn't support updating operations, e.g. delete sorry, waht about just using template.delete(5) or the orginal repository.delete(5)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should delete the relationship with the node you want to delete.
@Query("start u=node(5) delete u")

If you want to delete a node ,you should confirm the node haven't relationship with other node.
Please have a try with following codes:
@Query("start u=node(5) match u-[r]-() delete u,r")

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea, didn't try that yet b/c SDN still officially points to Neo4j 1.7 but that will change soon.

Why can't you update to SDN 2.1.RC2 ?

SDN 2.0.1 doesn't work with Neo4j 1.8 as there were API changes in Neo4j.

You will need to add `@Transactional` to the method as well.